# Applying style to fullscreen (from/to)

Tags: android

I've created an anim dir with 2 xml for fadein and fadeout, I solved using it with activities and dialogbuilder:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout);
```

Using this code to go to full screen I don't know how applying a style:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

How applying a style to fullscreen?

Comment: do you want style for fullscreen ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivityName"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

> 1.you can apply this maifest file

Answer (score 1):

Just like as..
In values/styles.xml

```
<resources> 
   <style name="CodeFont" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
      ...
   </style>
</resources>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@style/CodeFont">
```

Also can see..
http://ajitmahajani.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/android-full-screen-activity/
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
          ...